# How does a return statement differ from an equal sign?

Tags: javascript

Javascript is a functional language and functions are assigned values with the `return` statement.  As I learned Javascript I memorized the `return` statement as an `=` sign.  However as I've dug deeper I've come to realize that it doesn't always work the same and I can't see the pattern.  Are there a few obvious rules I need to remember?

For example in the code below `const pet` is assigned the key/value `cat: 10`.  But `pet.cat` comes back as `undefined`.

```js
"use strict";

const pet = function() {
    return {cat: 10};
}

pet();

console.log(pet.cat);
```

When written as a simple, object literal like below it worked perfectly as expected.  So clearly the `=` sign may be similar to `return` but they aren't quite the same.

```js
"use strict";

const pet = {cat: 10};

console.log(pet.cat);
```

Comment: first piece of code, pet is a **function** .. calling a function doesn't change `pet` to the result of the function!

Comment: No, they are NOT the same. Return returns a value from the function to caller. Assignment is assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const pet = function() {
  return {cat: 10};
}
```

Here an anonymous function is being assigned to `pet`. `pet` now has properties like [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) and [`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name), properties that apply to functions. But `cat` isn't a property of `pet`, it's a property of the object created when you run `pet`. You have to include those parentheses for the Javascript engine to understand that you want to run the function, not refer to the function itself. Only then can you make the mental substitution of the cat-containing object. So, if you want to see the `cat` property of the returned object, you would use `console.log(pet().cat);`.

Being able to refer to functions directly instead of running them all the time comes in handy! It lets us pass entire functions around, not just their results:

```
const func = function() {
  let r = Math.random();
  console.log(r);
}
window.setInterval(func, 1000);
```

This sends a random number to the console every second, because we passed the function we want to run to `window.setInterval`. If `func` was equivalent to its (undefined) return value, `window.setInterval` wouldn't get anything and wouldn't know what to do with it.

Comment: `console.log(pet().cat);`  Holy smokes now I get it!  That's how that property is addressed.  Maybe a month ago I started passing around functions as arguments and parameters.  I love that.   However sometimes they work fine and other times they crash and burn.  Your answer helps me a lot! It was worth all of the abuse x10.  Thanks!

Comment: Just remember that `pet` is getting run every time you address the `cat` property like that and it refers to a brand-new object every time. If `pet` is doing expensive work, you're better off storing the object in another variable, as in David's answer.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm not so much trying to make it work.  I'm trying to learn all of the different ways something can work.  Basically I'm trying to understand it like a spoken language.  When it began to sink in that JS was functional I started thinking of functions as nouns instead of verbs.  When in fact they are sort of both.

Comment: `pet().cat`   = When pet iterates get the value of the cat property.  That's the concept I was trying to understand.   I could not figure that out even though now it looks so easy and obvious.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing things. You cannot view `pet.cat` as there is no property on `pet` called `cat`. `pet` gets assigned to the function that returns `{ cat:10 }`. You'd need to save that off to another variable, like:

```
"use strict";

const pet = function() {
    return {cat: 10};
}

var stuffReturned = pet();

console.log(stuffReturned.cat);
```

Comment: `pet` doesn't really hold anything, it is just making that object up on-demand (when it is called).

Comment: `pet` is making that object up on the fly, here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/1fymeuha/